# Are transactions with multiple real inputs bound to require all the real inputs

Tags: transaction-unlock-time

I was reading [this](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1184) discussion on adding nLockTime to Monero, and the OP says that we can achieve this functionality by having a small amount of cryptocurrency transferred with an transaction-unlock-time and use this as a lock by having a multiple input transaction with this locked account to create a transaction that won't be valid until some time in the future.

The question is are these multiple real input transactions binding?  Meaning I have money in a 2-of-2 multisig account *A* where I own one of the keys and money in account *L*, where *L* is locked using transaction-unlock-time, and I have transaction that will be valid using *A* and *L* as real inputs back to to an output I hold (will be valid after *L* unlocks).

If I was a bad actor, could I separate the transaction and just send the money from *A* back to me by separating the transaction?  Or is this a hard problem?

EDIT:  The paragraph talking about multiple input is as follows:  "It is technically possible to implement nLockTime now (without protocol change), but it is a little clunky. You have to put a negligible amount of Monero in a time lock transaction, and then **sign a transaction spending it and the funds you want to nLockTime**. This won't be publishable until the other transaction is unlocked, but it is a little clunky, requiring a couple of transactions (and data must be published to the blockchain)."  The bold section implies a multiple input transaction.

Comment: Note I asked a similar question about time locking transactions earlier, but I feel like this approach required a new question.  https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11234/is-there-a-transaction-time-lock-mechanism-in-monero/11235#11235

Answer (score 1):

The OP workaround does not actually mimic a Bitcoin nLockTime tx, because the second tx (with the actual funds), is not *published* - it cannot be, the network would reject it. An nLockTime tx is actually *published* to the network but cannot be mined (included in a block) until the specified time has passed.

The moment a *Monero* tx is published, it can, and almost certainly will within 2 minutes, be mined. And as soon as it's mined/confirmed on the blockchain, it is ***final***, even if it has an unlock time set ([ref this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/813/7493)). This means the output(s) of that tx cannot be spent (used as inputs) in another tx, until the unlock time has passed.

Therefore, if you set an unlock time on a tx destined for a multisig wallet, the outputs of that tx, which are now owned by the multisig wallet, need to both pass the unlock time *and* be signed by *both* wallet participants to be spent. The tx cannot be cancelled and it can only be refunded* (sent back) once it has passed its locked time and signed by all participants.

(*) I say refunded here, but this is actually just a normal, manual, spend. There is presently no such thing as a tx refund address in Monero which would allow a more automated refund.

Pulling this all together, dissecting your question(s):

> The question is are these multiple real input transactions binding?

The moment a valid tx is sent to the network and mined/confirmed, it is binding. The input(s) must have been unlocked and you must have had the signing key(s) for them.

> Meaning I have money in a 2-of-2 multisig account A where I own one of
>   the keys and money in account L, where L is locked using
>   transaction-unlock-time, and I have a valid transaction using A and L
>   as real inputs back to to an output I hold.

You simply cannot have a situation like you have described here. It cannot be *both* "in a 2-of-2 multisig" wallet (locked or not) *and* in another wallet (locked or not). The moment you send (publish) the output to the multisig, it has to have been unlocked in your source wallet, and even if you specify it is to be locked when received in the multisig wallet, you cannot do anything with it after in the source wallet (it is now spent, regardless if it is now locked or not).

> If I was a bad actor, could I separate the transaction and just send
>   the money from A back to me by separating the transaction? Or is this
>   a hard problem?

Given you have defined A as a 2-2 multisig, the only way you can send it back to yourself is by having both the other signer sign this new transaction sending it back to you and the funds not being locked in the multisig. There is no gaming this.

Comment: Discussion of multiple inputs isn't explicit, but I believe it is there.  I edited in the paragraph to the question and made the section I think talks about multiple inputs bold.  Is that section not implying a multiple input transaction?

Comment: It is saying that Monero doesn't support it, but you can get around it to get the functionality.  The process they are describing is as follows:  1: Party one uses an unlock-transaction-time to put a small amount of money in account *A*.  2:  Create a transaction that transfers money out of *A* and *B* back to party one.  Account *B* is a multisig account between party one and two.  Both parties sign the transaction.  3.  Transfer money in to account *B*.   Now if the protocol fails, the money can be returned once the transaction to *A* is unlocked.

Comment: I read "sign a transaction spending *it* and *the funds you want to nLockTime*" as multiple inputs, seeing as the *it* they refer to is the negligible amount mentioned and *the funds you want to nLockTime* is another.  Note that this is a workaround for the lack of nLockTime, not an actual implementation of nLockTime within Monero.

Comment: To be clear, I know that a multisig account is an account that can not be spent from without the use of more than one key (or more than one part of a key), and that a multiple input transaction is a transaction that takes more than input (or spending account) in one transaction.

Comment: Updated answer based on your edited question and comments/clarifications.

Comment: So you are saying that the parts of the multi-input transaction (which will be invalid until the transaction to *L* has unlocked) can not be taken apart to get a valid single input transaction from one of the parts?

Comment: No I am saying, because you stated it is "in" the multisig wallet, it is therefore published on the network and mined in a block. And if it wasn't published, the other signer wouldn't see it in the multisig.

Comment: Also there is no notion of spending "part" of an output. Whole outputs are spent, and change comes back in a new change output. Also, there is no notion of locking one output and not another in a tx. All outputs are locked (or not).

Comment: I'm not concerned with wallet software here.  In protocols involving complicated movements of currency with Bitcoin, e.g. Tumblebit, it is common practice to lock down the amount of money in a multisig account, but create an escape transaction in case the protocol needs to abort.  This escape transaction has to be time delayed so that a bad actor can't use it before it is time.  However, the party putting in the money doesn't want the money put in until after he has the escape transaction in hand. Therefore, they create transactions before they are valid and hold on to them for insurance.

Comment: The "parts" I am referring to are the two ring signatures.  Is it possible to take one of the ring signatures from the 2 input transaction and use it to make your own transaction that only involves the money from its associated account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94232/discussion-between-jtgrassie-and-zarquan).